# Correct way to change android API

Tags: android, api, android-studio, gradle, build

I'm trying to lower down the Android API, from 23 to 16 by using android studio but I get error when project is run. I haave installed sdk version 18.

Before

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}
```

After

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

**Error**

```
  Error:(231, 62) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

After clean project

```
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-ldrtl-v23\values-ldrtl-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
```

Can someone please tell me how can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: have you tried clean and build?

Comment: A note that [best practice for compileSdkVerison](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#7d27) is to always compile with the latest SDK, even if you want to target a lower SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are compiling  your app with a lower SDK

```
compileSdkVersion 18
```

In SDK version 18 you don't have the support for Material Desgin:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"/>
```

You could also intgrate Material Design into your app by adding this dependency in your Gradle build:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
```

Check this link out:
[android-developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

You are getting this:

```
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-ldrtl-v23\values-ldrtl-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
C:\Users\tongws\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
```

Because the compiler cannot find the resources so it is either the solution that I posted from the link is old and it does not have those resources. It is probably the resources you are using are added in newer releases of the AppCompact so you need either need to create a new application project in android studio and copy the java files or change the designs to support lower SDKs

Also check whether you have the SDKs downloaded from Android SDK manager.
You need those tools and resources if you want to use them in your App

Comment: Yes if you want to to support lower SDKs

Comment: I have edited the answer check that solution and let me know

Comment: The support library should not use a lower version(21) than the targeted sdk

Comment: So you got that error when you added the code I mentioned above?

Comment: Do I need to remove  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' ?

Comment: Try it out and let me know

Comment: can you check again ?

Comment: Delete the buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" and delete     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' and replace it with the one in the answer

Comment: And try to clean your app or rebuild it

Comment: please check. Do I need to change anything in mainfest ?

Comment: How to change the design ?

Comment: Okay check my answer now